# Best way to add support for a new subnet

Tags: routes, ip, dhcp, subnet

I currently have a network where all of the clients are served 192.168.0.0 subnet addresses with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.  Since I am running out of addresses to serve within that subnet, I would like clients to start being served 192.168.4.0 subnet addresses as well, but am unsure of the easiest way to do this.

My current thinking is that I should modify my DHCP server to start serving 192.168.4.0 addresses while modifying all subnet masks being served to 255.255.0.0.  However, I think I would have to go and change any static IP addresses that I have configured to use the new subnet mask in order to communicate with the new subnet.  Is there a way to add this new subnet without having to modify my already-existing static configurations for the 192.168.0.0 subnet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess the short answer to this question is no.  I ended up doing some doing some cleanup and expanding the DCHP address range for the existing subnet, but if I want to add support for ranges outside of the subnet it looks like I'll have to manually change some subnet masks.